# Gridpanel prepare submenu

Tags: javascript, extjs, ext.net

I am having issues with my prepare function. I am trying to select the `Delete button` to be able to disable/enable it. This is the code to select the first item (which would be the dropdown group). I am trying to select the first item within that group.

```
var prepareRecruiter = function (grid, toolbar, rowIndex, record) {
var dropdown = toolbar.items.get(0);
dropdown.setDisabled(true);
};
```

I tried multiple variations along the lines of `toolbar.items.get(0).get(0);` and `toolbar.items.items.get(0);` without success.

How do I select the delete button so i can disable it?

[image]

I have the following code for my gridcommand:

```
<ext:CommandColumn runat="server" Width="35" Sortable="false" fixed="true" meta:resourcekey="CommandColumnResource2" ID="ctl2108">
    <Commands>
        <ext:GridCommand Icon="ApplicationForm">
            <Menu EnableScrolling="false">
                <Items>
                    <ext:MenuCommand Text="Delete" Icon="ApplicationFormDelete" CommandName="Delete" meta:resourcekey="DeleteCommandResource1" />
                    <ext:MenuCommand Text="Disable" Icon="ApplicationFormDisable" CommandName="Disable" />
                    <ext:MenuCommand Text="Enable" Icon="ApplicationFormEnable" CommandName="Enable" />
                </Items>
            </Menu>
        </ext:GridCommand>
    </Commands>
    <PrepareToolbar Fn="prepareRecruiter" />
    <Listeners>
        <Command Fn="REDcommand" />
    </Listeners>
</ext:CommandColumn>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use "button.menu" to get access to the Menu's items.

**Example**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!X.IsAjaxRequest)
        {
            Store store = this.GridPanel1.GetStore();
            store.DataSource = new object[] 
            { 
                new object[] { "test", "test" },
                new object[] { "test", "test" },
                new object[] { "test", "test" }
            };
        }
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET v2 Example</title>

    <script>
        var prepareToolbar = function (grid, toolbar, rowIndex, record) {
            var btn = toolbar.items.get(0);

            btn.menu.items.get(0).disable();
        }; 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

        <ext:GridPanel ID="GridPanel1" runat="server">
            <Store>
                <ext:Store runat="server">
                    <Model>
                        <ext:Model runat="server">
                            <Fields>
                                <ext:ModelField Name="test1" />
                                <ext:ModelField Name="test2" />
                            </Fields>
                        </ext:Model>
                    </Model>
                </ext:Store>
            </Store>
            <ColumnModel runat="server">
                <Columns>
                    <ext:Column runat="server" Text="Test 1" DataIndex="test1" />
                    <ext:Column runat="server" Text="Test 2" DataIndex="test2" />
                    <ext:CommandColumn runat="server" Width="35">
                        <Commands>
                            <ext:GridCommand Icon="ApplicationForm">
                                <Menu>
                                    <Items>
                                        <ext:MenuCommand Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" />
                                        <ext:MenuCommand Text="Disable" CommandName="Disable" />
                                        <ext:MenuCommand Text="Enable" CommandName="Enable" />
                                    </Items>
                                </Menu>
                            </ext:GridCommand>
                        </Commands>
                        <PrepareToolbar Fn="prepareToolbar" />
                    </ext:CommandColumn>
                </Columns>
            </ColumnModel>
        </ext:GridPanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that logically makes a lot of sense. I have since changed the way I built the page, so I can not test this answer, but I will keep it in mind for future projects.